# > character sequences can really mess up the layout and make loading/editing the question very difficult

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, edits

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306597/problem-in-silverlight-tree-view-drag-and-drop#

Apparently, some code in this question is seriously messing up both the view and the editing properties. I'm trying to get to the edit now for 5 minutes, but it's unable to load. Is this a server problem or did the post really cause some trouble? The rest of SO works normally, but for that post I get 505 Gateway Timeout.

---

EDIT : I managed to edit the post, so now everything is back to normal. Still, it might be worth looking a bit deeper into it. Apparently a set of

```
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

characters can really, really mess up the layout and cause big trouble

A small demonstration

> > > Here

Comment: Wow...you're not wrong there. Even the edit history is borked because of that.

Comment: Yeah, I have a feeling there's never a legitimate reason to allow people to nest blockquotes 74 deep. Wow.

Comment: @Tim, to be fair, it looks like the OP was just using those as cheap horizontal rules. I'm guessing he didn't bother reading about Markdown and had no idea he was creating blockquote craziness.

Comment: @PopularDemand Oh, of course. I meant more that there's no legitimate reason to do it, so perhaps the system can prevent it from happening accidentally as it did here. I'm not sure that the Markdown parser would be aware of the nesting though, so perhaps not.

Answer (score 3):

This was fixed a while ago and also recently added to the open source version (I forgot to do that earlier) as http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/source/detail?r=c8ec1e22b0af05b9b5b1c53d3e23d655f6bbb2e3.